# iPhone-friendly browser audio play button

Tags: iphone, flash, html, audio

The old way to allow audio to be played/streamed in the browser was a flash button, such as that seen on www.irish-sayings.com .

What's the new iPhone-friendly way to give the ability to click on a simple button to listen to an audio file in the browser?

If the answer is HTML5, is the such a button built and available? I don't need an MP3 player with steaming and such, only a button.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the audio tag.

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="song.mp3" />
<!-- You can include some fallback for browsers that do not support this -->
</audio>
```

Comment: Ok, that shows a small play "bar" (Firefox). To minimise that to a single play button, I guess I need to implement that with JavaScript + HTML 5?

Comment: Yip, you would remove the controls parameter give it an id (e.g. audio for reference) and then style it yourself using JavaScript and CSS. Example `<button onClick="document.getElementById('audio').play()">`